# undefined method process for carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a simple model that mounts a Carrierwave uploader. Ruby version 2.2.3, Ruby on Rails 4.2.4, Imagemagick is installed on mac (10.11.1 El Capitan). MiniMagick 4.3.6 gem is installed; however, I get the error ***undefined method process for*** uploader.

[image]

The gem file:

```
gem "fog-google"
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem "mini_magick"
```

The uploader is mounted on the model:

```
mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
```

The model has the attribute `:avatars`

**avatar_uploader.rb** : (commented lines are removed for clarity)

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    'uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}'
  end

  process :scale => [300, 300]

  def scale(width, height)
    process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

Any clues on what could this be?

Comment: try `class.process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]` in your `scale` method

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to do

```
process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]
```

instead of:

```
process :scale => [300, 300]

def scale(width, height)
  process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]
end
```

Comment: Indeed this works; however, why does the other way doesn't work?

Comment: @jasa I think it's just ilegal to call process there, also after being called by process. Does my answer fit with what you wanted to do? Or you wanted to do something else?